# Read huge nvarchar(max) as UTF-16 stream without saturate memory

Tags: c#, sql-server, utf-16, .net-8.0, nvarchar

I am developing a program that reads text from sql server nvarchar(max) field and needs to write it as UTF-16 text file inside a zip.

I cannot load the string contained in the field as it weighs >1GB and would saturate memory

What I am trying to do is to get a stream directly into a .zip created on the fly

I found a method but I do not get a valid utf-16 file as I read the bytes of the sql field directly. Do you have another approach?

```
using (SqlDataReader Rd = DbMan.GetDbReader(command, CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess) as SqlDataReader) //Opens a datareader in SequentialAccess fro not impacting on memory
{
    using (MemoryStream MSZip = new MemoryStream()) //This stream contains the .zip created on the fly
    {
        using (var Zip = new ZipArchive(MSZip, ZipArchiveMode.Create)) //Creating .zip
        {
            while (Rd.Read())
            {
                var FileJsonInsideZip = Zip.CreateEntry("MyFile${Rd.GetString(0)}.json", CompressionLevel.Fastest); //Creating the empty file inside .zip

            using (var StreamFileInsideZip = FileJsonInsideZip.Open()) //This stream is the file created inside the .zip
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8096]; //Reading 8096 bytes and adds progressively to zip, to not saturate the memory
                long offset = 0;
                long read;
                while ((read = Rd.GetBytes(1, offset, buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    offset += read;
                    StreamFileInsideZip.Write(buffer, 0, (int)read);
                }
                
            }

        }

    }
}
}
```

I also try with TextReader, this approach produce a valid UTF-16 file, but saturate the memory

```
byte[] sUtf16Bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Rd.GetTextReader(1).ReadToEnd());
StreamFileInsideZip.Write(sUtf16Bytes, 0, sUtf16Bytes.Length);
```

EDIT: Sorry, the first code produced a valid file but without BOM. The generated JSON file is imported into sql server, without BOM upon import I was getting the error "SINGLE_NCLOB requires a UNICODE (widechar) input file. The file specified is not Unicode." which misled me

Comment: It is one of the fastest possible ways to solve that problem imo. You are not adding any extra layer, you take data directly from the reader, so IMO there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik Everything works and the use of memory is very efficient, but reading the bytes from the SQL field I don't get a file with valid UTF-16 encoding.  With the second piece of code I get a valid utf-16 file (it is twice the size of the first file rightly) but this involves loading the entire SQL field into memory

Comment: What kind of bytes data do you get? if you test with some small string like "test"? IMHO, GetBytes shouldn't necessarily mangle any strings

Comment: @matti157 Have you tried to mix those 2 approaches? Inside the second while, have you tried using `Encoding` class to read in `UTF-16`, but not entire column, just what you have just read in that second while  using offsets? Maybe its worth a try:  `byte[] sUtf16Bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(buffer);` and then write that bytes to zip file `StreamFileInsideZip.Write(sUtf16Bytes, 0, sUtf16Bytes.Length); `

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik I figured out why the file was invalid, both writing directly from the SQL field and adding Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes do not put the first byte of the file to FF! Basically, there is no BOM

Comment: BOM shouldn't matter in theory, as long as you know upfront what the encoding should be. If you need to write it yiou can use `Encoding.Unicode.Preamble`

Comment: Agree, you made it sound like the file got completely corrupted

Comment: @siggemannen Sorry, the generated JSON file is imported into sql server, without BOM upon import I was getting the error "SINGLE_NCLOB requires a UNICODE (widechar) input file. The file specified is not Unicode." which misled me

Comment: You can use [SqlDataReader.GetStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstream?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) and copy to `StreamFileInsideZip` directly with `Stream.CopyTo`. If you want to add a BOM you'll have to do so before calling `CopyTo`

Comment: If you use a MemoryStream you're still storing everything in memory. Create a file-based package at least. Another option is to wrap a GZipStream over a FileStream to write directly to a `.gz` file without keeping anything in memory. Compression may not be as great but memory usage will be a lot less

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually the MemoryStream is a .zip file, in fact I have in the nvarchar field a json of about 700MB and the program does not occupy more than 50MB

Comment: That's still 50MB that doesn't have to be in memory. In fact, due to buffer resizing, it's 100MB in log2(100M) buffers. Zipping requires more memory than just the final package

Answer (score 1):

You should move the buffer outside the loop.

Maybe also initialize the `MemoryStream` to some large buffer size to avoid copying.

```cs
byte[] buffer = new byte[8096]; //Reading 8096 bytes and adds progressively to zip, to not saturate the memory

using SqlDataReader Rd = (SqlDataReader)DbMan.GetDbReader(command, CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
using MemoryStream MSZip = new MemoryStream() //This stream contains the .zip created on the fly
using (var Zip = new ZipArchive(MSZip, ZipArchiveMode.Create, leaveOpen: true)) //Creating .zip, leave it open so you can use MSZip after
{
    while (Rd.Read())
    {
        var FileJsonInsideZip = Zip.CreateEntry($"MyFile{Rd.GetString(0)}.json", CompressionLevel.Fastest); //Creating the empty file inside .zip

        using var StreamFileInsideZip = FileJsonInsideZip.Open(); //This stream is the file created inside the .zip
        long offset = 0;
        long read;
        while ((read = Rd.GetBytes(1, offset, buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            offset += read;
            StreamFileInsideZip.Write(buffer, 0, (int)read);
        }
    }
}
MSZip.Position = 0;  // reset position of memorystream to copy somewhere else
```